# Why does not Stack Overflow support reading view?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I like when I am on my iPhone and browse blogs that I am able to transform the page into reader view. I want to do same thing in Microsoft Edge (desktop) as well for instance.

Why does Stack Overflow not support this feature?

EDIT: Okay, turns out this is available for Firefox browser, but my question is in general.

Comment: It does support Reader View on Firefox.

Comment: I don't see it, but to honest having it for one of the many browsers out there doesn't mean this feature is supported, if I have to use firefox only for stackoverflow I'd rather give up reader view luxury.
EDIT: Okay I saw it, so there is for Firefox, but the question remains for others.

Comment: @S.L.Barth It only renders the question, not the answers.

Comment: The vote arrows are a rather important feature of this site for registered users. If, as you're reading, you come across something useful (or not useful) to you, then you really should be voting on it. A reader that stripped away all content would discourage that, and we don't want to discourage that.

Comment: That might actually be reasonable argument for not providing reader view...

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow is not a blog, and its content often isn't a good fit for "reader" view.

Mobile browsers are already perfectly capable of delivering SE content.
For a even better view on mobile phones, you can also use Stack Overflow’s app. ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.stackoverflow&hl=en), [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-overflow/id1155618808?mt=8))

Comment: Most of the good questions are closed/documented and are so well written that it becomes even better place than a blog, not to mention documentation initiative... I don't think this is the main reason. Yes I am using mobile applications, but I am asking about desktop, maybe I should rephrase it.

Comment: `its content often isn't a good fit for "reader" view` That's not true at all.  The *primary* use case for using the site; the use case that accounts for the *majority* of the site's views, is someone finding a question in Google that's related to their problem, and then finding an answer to it, most likely without them even having an account (although without them needing to submit content even if they do).

Comment: @kuskmen I would expect very few *good* questions to be closed.  Questions are closed when they're not suitable for the site, which is generally not true of good questions.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, maybe I don't use the right words today, maybe its more suitable to use the word locked.
Take example this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Servy: "reader view" is not the same as "readonly". I think you're mis-understanding the question. [Here's some info on what "reader view" is.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-reader-view-clutter-free-web-pages)

Comment: @kuskmen Good questions are very rarely going to be locked.  Questions are locked to prevent people from interacting with them because too many people have been *inappropriate* interacting with them, usually this means abusive edits.  Most locks are temporary (to stop disputes that are happening).  This is a rare exceptional case that has gotten a permanent lock due to many hundreds of people constantly making abusive edits to a good post over an extended period of time.  It is in no way typical for a good question to be locked, as most aren't abusively edited.

Comment: @Cerbrus My understanding of reader view is that it's removing what elements from the page isn't necessary for one to read through the content that it has.   In the case of SO, what would be removed is the buttons/textboxes/etc. that one uses to interact with the question, just leaving the content to be read.  So I stand by my original comment.

Comment: @Servy: What about code blocks? Indentation? Tags? User information? There's too much important markup that will disappear / be ruined by a typical "reader view" implementation. A specialized mobile view (app!) is a better option.

Comment: @Cerbrus If So was to create their own reader view, they obviously wouldn't want to remove code blocks, or tags, or (at least most of) the user information.  Just relying on entirely automatic browser behavior would indeed be...unlikely, to work well. That's why this is a feature request to SO, and not someone just saying that they use a browsers default reader view.

Comment: @Cerbrus There is no reason at all for SO to utterly fail in it's primary use case of someone searching for a question and being able to read the answer when using a mobile browser.  Requiring someone download an app just to be able to read some text on a page is going to be a complete non-starter for most of your users, and it's an unreasonable request.  An app can be beneficial for power users who want to have more features than a browser alone can offer, but there is no excuse for SE not having a good user experience for searching on google and reading a QA using a web browser.

Comment: @Servy: That's assuming mobile browsers fail at properly delivering SE's content, which they don't.

Comment: @Cerbrus So then say *that* as an answer.  If the current behavior is already fine, then that's a great reason not to implement this feature, as it'd be unnecessary.  Saying that people don't need an effective browser UI for reading SO content on the other hand *isn't* a good reason not to support something like this.

Comment: @Servy: Fair enough. What do you think of the edit?

Comment: Still not really a fan of the first sentence, at least as it's worded now.